# Socket connection from PC to device fails

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket, android-networking

I'm using sockets for a client-server application (i.e. the client sends data and the server received the data). My code is below. When I use the client in an Android 5.1 application on a tablet and the server in a Java application on a Windows 7 PC it works very well (i.e. the tablet can send data to the PC). But when I try to use the server code on the Android 5.1 application on the tablet and the client code on the PC (i.e. sending data from the PC to the tablet) the connection cannot be established and I'm getting the error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The tablet and the PC are in the same network.

What is wrong?

Server:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(13005);
Socket socket = ss.accept();
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Client:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.2.130.125", 13005));
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

Edit:

I have now executed `netstat -nap`. The output is as follows (I have altered the foreign addresses slightly). 13005 seems not to be used.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 tcp     417      0 10.2.130.125:36844     xxx.xxx.23.74:443      CLOSE_WAIT
 tcp     417      0 10.2.130.125:35996     xxx.xxx.23.110:443     CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ::ffff:10.2.130.125:44994 ::ffff:xxx.xx.205.170:443 CLOSE_WA
IT
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.2.130.125:43995 ::ffff:xx.xx.119.188:5228 ESTABL
ISHED
tcp6       1      0 ::ffff:10.2.130.125:42353 ::ffff:xx.xx.23.110:80 CLOSE_WAI
T
tcp6       1      0 ::ffff:10.2.130.125:35722 ::ffff:xx.xx.205.170:443 CLOSE_WA
IT
tcp6       1      0 ::ffff:10.2.130.125:48101 ::ffff:xx.xx.205.110:443 CLOSE_WA
IT
```

I have also executed `nmap -sS -Pn -p- 10.2.130.125`. The output is:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-18 16:10 W. Europe Standard T
ime
Nmap scan report for public-docking-cx-0635.ethz.ch (10.2.130.125)
Host is up (0.059s latency).
Not shown: 65534 filtered ports
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 159.90 seconds
```

Here is the stacktrace from the client. It is just a timeout exception. From the server I don't get any exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at inf.ethz.ch.streaming.server.main.Main$1.run(Main.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the port is open in the android tablet?

Comment: You will need some form of inspection like telnet to see if the port is actually open. Is the IP address correct?

Comment: @f1sh The ip address is correct, I have it from settings -> About tablet -> Status -> ip address. It is the network address of my device.

Comment: @SantiagoSalem Acutally, I don't know if the port is open on my tablet. How can I check that or which port can I use instead?

Comment: @f1sh I have now used telnet and it turned out that the port is not open (telnet says that it could not open connection to host).

Comment: @machinery Could you edit your post adding the stacktrace?

Comment: @SantiagoSalem I have done the edit

Comment: @machinery Did you make a ping from the PC to the android device?

Comment: @SantiagoSalem Ping works from my PC to the android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the port 13005 is being used, probably the last connection was not closed.

Connect your device via USB. Then go to the folder where you have `adb` and run the following:

1. `adb shell`
2. `netstat -nap`

This will show you all the active ports in the android device. You will be able to check if port 13005 is being used.

If you have lot of connections, then is better to apply grep to step 2.

2. `netstat -na |grep 13005`

Then try to use another port, for example 5001. If the port is not restricted and is free, you should be able to connect.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please see my edits in the original post. 13005 seems not to be used and with 5001 it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Client and server should just be exchanged but in my actual code I have it the right why.

Comment: @machinery and trying with ports in the range of 49152 and 65535? Your code seems ok. It should be something else. Do you have the internet permission set in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have set the internet permission in the manifest file. The ports you mentionend are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the port is available from outside?
You have to open the port in your router configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure if the port is available from outside. I have used the same port at my PC when I have made a socket connection from my tablet to my pc and this worked. So I think the router is not the problem.

Comment: I have now tried telnet 10.2.130.125 13005 and it could not connect. How can I open this port in Android or which other port should work?